# AdGuard Appliance On Pi 3 Fails to Boot

Tags: boot, raspberrypi

I downloaded the AdGuard Home appliance for my Raspberry Pi 3 and flashed to an SD card using the Raspberry Pi Imager.  When I try to boot the Pi, it gets stuck on the splashcreen with the Core logo.  The green light on the Pi is flashing sort of like a heartbeat (think flash-flash, pause, flash-flash, pause) repeatedly, and the red light is on steadily.  I'm able to flash and run Raspberry Pi OS Lite on this Pi with this SD card without issue, so I don't think the problem is with my Pi, SD card, or power supply.

Answer (score 0):

You have done all of the troubleshooting that you can. An Ubuntu Core Appliance has no user access to a shell or to other troubleshooting tools.

Please [report the problem directly to the upstream authors](https://adguard.com/en/support.html). They created both the Snap and the Appliance.